# External monitor connected via HDMI doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 - Intel HD + NVIDIA GT750M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have this problem with my Lenovo IdeaPad Core17, Intel HD and Nvidia GT750M graphics card running a dual boot of Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.
On Windows everything works fine but on Ubuntu, HDMI isn't working for external monitors and I'm getting a black screen if I close the lid or suspend the laptop which forces a hard power off.

Answer (score 1):

From question's [revision #1](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1212787/revisions/1):

> 1. First check the recommended nVidia drivers .
>
>    ```
>    sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
>    ```
> 2. Install the recommended driver, in my case, it were nvidia-418.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install nvidia-418
>    ```
> 3. Install nvidia-prime and nvidia-settings
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
>    ```
> 4. Reboot. You will probably get into a login loop.
> 5. If 4 above happens edit `/etc/default/grub` and look for the line
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
>    ```
>
>    and remove `nomodeset`.
>
>    This was only necessary when installing Ubuntu. Now it's just causing
>    your video drivers not to be loaded.
> 6. Run
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-grub
>    ```
>
> HDMI should work now. If the audio stops working, run
>
> ```
> pulseaudio -k
> ```
>
> and then go to System Settings→Sound and set HDMI as default audio.
>
> ---
>
> #### Links That helped me:
>
> - [Ubuntu 16.04 login loop GeForce GTX 1060 - GPU Unix Graphics / Linux - NVIDIA Developer
>   Forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1038478/linux/ubuntu-16-04-login-loop-geforce-gtx-1060/)
> - [Fix No Sound Through HDMI In External Monitor In Ubuntu Linux - It's
>   FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/)
> - [How can I Install/Activate Intel video driver? - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2042773)